# How can I convert a wstring containing Chinese or Korean into hex/bytes?

Tags: c++

I have a program that needs to be able to make the hexadecimal representation of English, Chinese, or Korean words (depending on the users language selection) and store it in a buffer.

I do this quite easily with English characters by doing the following...

```
const std::wstring word_sample = "SampleWord";  
const int size = static_cast<int>(word_sample.size());

AddDataToBuffer(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&stringSize), sizeof(size));

AddDataToBuffer(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(word_sample .c_str()), size);
```

However, when I try to do this with Chinese or Korean (languages that combine multiple symbols into one character), it comes out as gibberish when received by the client.

I found out that this is because I need to have EACH symbol (not each character) converted into hex for the buffer.

So for example, with this Chinese text, "防身刀", the total size should be 6 and the hex output should be

```
0xb7, 0xc0, 0xc9, 0xed, 0xb5, 0xb6
```

My problem is that I have no idea how to actually determine if a character is comprised of multiple symbols & split it into symbols...

Comment: At least you need to replace `size` in the second call with `size * sizeof(wchar_t)`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat if it were that easy, the ASCII string would be chopped in half already.

Comment: Your example English text contains 10 characters, so you add 10 bytes to the buffer - but half (if you are on Windows) or three quarters (if you are on Linux) of those bytes will be null.  Exactly *what* is the client expecting to recieve?  UTC-4? UTF16-LE? UTF16-BE? UTF8? ASCII with unicode characters escaped in some way?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that might work for Chinese (I'm not sure)... but it would break for English & Korean at least..

Comment: @Rick why would it break for English?

Comment: You seem to think that different characters in your strings occupy different number of bytes. That's (probably) not true. (That would be true if you used UTF-8.)

Comment: Do you know what encoding is used for the wide characters? If it's UTF-16 then you'll need a code page translation.

Comment: @MartinBonner it would break because for english... the size would be 10, but with the * sizeof(wchar_t) it would be 20. I just tested it.... and only the first letter ended up showing on the client lol.

Comment: @Rick, how did you display those bytes?  If you treated them as a null-terminated string of narrow characters, then yes, it will break.  You need to treat them as a sequence of wchar_t characters (and hope that the client has the same definition of wchar_t as the server).

Comment: @MartinBonner the client does expect & require each string to be null terminated (I left that part out).

Comment: If you can change that (i.e. pass length separately), you probably should, otherwise you need to bother with encoding/decoding.

Comment: I need to convert the encoding to GBK... trying to find out how now.

Comment: @Rick "How to convert from std::wstring to GBK format" would be a *much* better question that this one.  You need to indicate your platform (because, eg, Windows may be able to do it for you)

Comment: You provide an example of what you _expect_ from the Chinese, but you don't indicate what you _actually get_. Please provide this information; it will help clarify your issue, and may provide additional clues toward solving it.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs into a similar situation... In my case, I had to use UTF-8 encoding to store the values in a wstring. Then, I converted the wstring to a string and provided a code page specific to the language I needed.